# Dynamics array from function to function in C visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, dynamic-arrays

I need to transfer from function to function. I try like this:

```
    double toarray(double x,int n)
{
    double * results = new double[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        results[j] = function( x);
        x += jump;
    }
    return *results;
}

void showarr(double*arr[],int n,double x)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Wynik dla x=" "%.2lf", x);
        if (denomcheck(x) == true && function(x)<INT_MAX)
        {
            printf(" | y=%.2lf \n", arr[i]);
        }
        else
            printf(" | MIANOWNIK = 0!!! \n");
        x += jump;
    } 
}
```

But when I try to call out toarray as an variable of showarr:

```
showarr(toarray(x, n), n, x);
```

I get E0167 error in vs 2017.

"argument type "double" is incompatible with parameter type "double **""

Comment: `toarray()` should return `double *`, not `double`.  Your compiler should be warning you about that, too.  Additionally, `showarr()` should accept `double *`, not `double *[]`.

Comment: You are messing `C` with `C++`, Why?

Comment: @WG97  Make a proposal to the C Standard Committee that the types double and double ** would be compatible.

Comment: Who is `delete[]`-ing the array when `showarr` is done with it? And why can you not use a `std::vector<double>`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Assuming `jump` and `function` are declared outside, I don't see why a compiler should warn about the implementation of `toarray` (unless the compiler does some static leak-checking)

Comment: I can not use vector becouse it's a task. I had to use array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `toarray` should return a pointer to an array, not a single double value:

```
double *toarray(double x,int n) {
     double * results = new double[n];
     ...
     return results;
}
```

And `showarr` should process an array of doubles (passed as a pointer to such an array, either written as `double arr[]` or as `double *`) instead of an array of pointers to doubles (which is the meaning of `double *arr[]`):

```
void showarr(double arr[],int n,double x) {
    ...
```

Further, you should delete the array you created, i.e. use `delete[] arr` at a point where `arr` is not needed afterwards.

Comment: Worth mentioning that a function parameter `double arr[]` is actually `double* arr`, not an "array".